# I am having this error in charts v3 chartjs-chart-treemap: fontColor does not exist in type 'ChartDataset<"treemap", TreemapDataPoint[]>

Tags: angular, chart.js, treemap

I have a Angular 13 Chartjs 3.6 application that's given the above error in the following:

```
this.cryptoChart = new Chart(this.ctx, {
       type: 'treemap',   //'treemap',
       data: {
            datasets: [{
              tree: this.treeData,
              key: 'value',
              groups: ['coin'],
              spacing: 0.5,
              borderWidth: 1.5,
              *fontColor: 'Black',*
              borderColor: "grey"
            }],
          },
        options: {
                  maintainAspectRatio: false,
                  *legend: { display: false },*
                  tooltips: { enabled: false }
                
                }
      });
```

This is the full error message:

```
Type '{ tree: any; key: string; groups: string[]; spacing: number; borderWidth: number; fontColor: string; borderColor: string; }' is not assignable to type 'ChartDataset<"treemap", TreemapDataPoint[]>'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'fontColor' does not exist in type 'ChartDataset<"treemap", TreemapDataPoint[]>'.ts(2322)
```

A similar error occurs on options..legend property.

I also have:
import Chart from 'chart.js/auto';
import {TreemapController, TreemapElement} from 'chartjs-chart-treemap';
AND in

```
 ngOnInit(){
    Chart.register(TreemapController, TreemapElement);
    this.coinChart = document.getElementById('coinChart');
    this.ctx = this.coinChart.getContext("2d");
    .......
    .......
    }
```

apparently I a missing a step in the integration....will appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the documentation of the treemap it doesnt support the `fontColor` property. To change the color of the labels you need to define it either in:

- `data.datasets[datasetIndex].labels.color`
- `options.datasets.treemap.labels.color`
- `options.elements.treemap.labels.color`

Since it looks like you want it in the dataset, your datasets array would look like this:

```js
datasets: [{
  tree: this.treeData,
  key: 'value',
  groups: ['coin'],
  spacing: 0.5,
  borderWidth: 1.5,
  labels: {
    color: 'black'
  }
  borderColor: "grey"
}],
```

On a side note your options object is also wrong, you are using V2 syntax in V3, the tooltip and legend config have been moved to the plugins namespace, for all changes you can read the [migration guide](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/master/getting-started/v3-migration.html)

Comment: This didn't work...once you remove fontColor and/or add labels this error shows up: Type '{ tree: any; key: string; groups: string[]; spacing: number; borderWidth: number; borderColor: string; }' is not assignable to type 'ChartDataset<"treemap", TreemapDataPoint[]>'.
  Property 'data' is missing in type '{ tree: any; key: string; groups: string[]; spacing: number; borderWidth: number; borderColor: string; }' but required in type 'ChartDatasetProperties<"treemap", TreemapDataPoint[]>'.ts(2322)

Comment: It did work since the error went away, you just got another error in return for it. It says the data field is missing but the typings file says it should be auto generated so that sounds like a bug in the lib to me: https://github.com/kurkle/chartjs-chart-treemap/blob/next/types/index.esm.d.ts#L66

Comment: Ok....hopefully someone knows what's going on with this bug.

Comment: By adding data: [] to the datasets the error goes away.....but this is obviously not the solution....would appreciate any help here.